# EAAccessory to accept all protocol string

Tags: iphone

In the documentation of EAAccessoryManager it says we need to add "Supported external accessory protocols" in the settings plist. But this can be done for known protocol strings. What if I don't know the protocol string or string which are not in the list, if my application has to detect any arbitrary device which are "made for iPod" how do I do that?

And also how do I know the Protocol String of the Device?  Where to find this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want retrieve the protocolString try this:

```
//Load all connected accessories
    NSMutableArray *_accessoryList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];
//Load attribute protocolString into NSString, note that the "objectAtIndex" is just to show the string on a UITableViewCell of a UITableView.
    NSString *eaAccessoryProtocolString = [[_accessoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] protocolString];
```

In the Info.plist you have to add the protocol that the devices implement and it must be the same of the application. In this case you need to contact manufacturer, otherwise you have to apply the MFi/WWi license and than you can define your own protocols, like Data schema for sent and revive data to and from external devices.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Yes this again requires us to specify atleast some protocol string , but is there any universal string which can accept any device connected ?

Comment: No, and I think this is by design. They don't want you to be able to snoop on other devices. Imagine what you could do if you were able to intercept a credit card reader!

Comment: You can get the supported protocol strings without contacting the manufacturer.  Apple's own sample code EADemo does it.

Comment: @Boon That's strictly true, but you will not be able to open an EASession for a given protocol string *unless* that string was already included in your info.plist at compile-time...so you can "see" any connected EAAccessory and poll it for basic info (protocols, display name, mfr, S/N), but you won't be able to open a session and communicate in any meaningful way.

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer. As @Reid mentioned, it tells you how to get a chicken by telling you to get a chicken egg first.

Comment: @Reid what you mention does not seem to hold true anymore. I tested on iOS 12 and `[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]]` always returns an empty array unless I add the correct protocol string in the app's plist. It would be interesting to know which iOS version allowed this.